# JPA connection of several tables to one

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have two different tables (mapped to JPA entities) - `Student` and `Teacher` and another table `Passport`; each `Passport` can be owned by either a `Student` or a `Teacher` but not both at the same time. No student/teacher can have more than one passport. Now I see three options of implementing this relation:

1. Adding an extra field (pasport_id) to student and teacher tables;
2. Adding two fields (teacher_id, student_id) to passport table;
3. Creating two join tables (for student -> passport and teacher -> passport).

Which of these three is better and why?

Comment: Assuming suggestion no 3: Teacher and Student inherits from Passport. You could use a discriminator. See https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_discrim.html

Comment: 1. because for 3. you would also need 1.

Comment: Adding two fields (owner_type, owner_id) to passport table;

Comment: then we won't be able to have db constraint on owner_id